# Ng-Model returning null instead of nothing

Tags: html, angularjs, sqlite

I am returning objects from a Sqlite database that sometimes returns null for some attributes of this object. For example (item.unit) is sometimes null in the database.

I got this code in my html file

```
<td class="item-row-quote"><span class="quote-price-text" ng-model="row.dollarPerUnitText"
                                                 id="dollarPerUnit">{{ '$/' + item.unit }}</span></td>
```

How can I make sure the browser display nothing for item.unit instead of displaying null.

---

This is my controller code

```
angular.module('canex')
.controller("QuoteController", ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'ProjectService', 'QuoteService', 'UploadService', 'ClientService', 'ItemService', 'ConditionService',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, projectService, quoteService, uploadService, clientService, itemService, conditionService) {
        $scope.clientId = $routeParams.clientId;
        $scope.projectId = $routeParams.projectId;
        $scope.quoteId = $routeParams.quoteId;
        $scope.IMG_URL = uploadService.getImageUrl();
        $scope.quoteDate = new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);
        $scope.items = [];


        function _fetchQuote() {
            quoteService.getQuote($routeParams.quoteId)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.quote = response.data;
                }, $scope.httpErrorCallback);
        }

        function _fetchItems() {
            itemService.getQuoteItems($routeParams.quoteId)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.items = response.data;
                }, $scope.httpErrorCallback);
        }

        function _fetchConditions() {
            conditionService.getQuoteConditions($routeParams.quoteId)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.conditions = response.data;
                }, $scope.httpErrorCallback);
        }


        function _fetchClient() {
            clientService.getClient($routeParams.clientId)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.client = response.data;
                }, $scope.httpErrorCallback);
        }

        function _fetchProject() {
            projectService.getProject($routeParams.projectId)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.project = response.data;
                }, $scope.httpErrorCallback);
        }


        $scope.addRow = function () {
            $scope.items.data.push({});
        };

        $scope.addCondition = function () {
            if (document.getElementById("condition-page").style.display == "none") {
                document.getElementById("condition-page").style.display = '';
            }
            $scope.conditions.data.push({})
        };

        $scope.removeRow = function (index) {
            var itemId = $scope.items.data[index].id;
            itemService.archiveItem(itemId);
            $scope.items.data.splice(index, 1);
        };

        $scope.removeCondition = function (index) {
            var conditionId = $scope.conditions.data[index].id;
            conditionService.archiveCondition(conditionId);
            $scope.conditions.data.splice(index, 1);
        };

        $scope.subtotal = function () {
            var subtotal = 0;
            angular.forEach($scope.items.data, function (item) {
                subtotal += item.quantity * item.rate;
            });
            return subtotal;
        };

        $scope.generateQuote = function (divName) {
            $scope.submitItems();
            $scope.submitConditions();
            if ($scope.conditions.data.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById("condition-page").style.display = "none";
            }
            var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
            var popupWin;
            if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
                popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=600,height=800,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,titlebar=no');
                popupWin.window.focus();
                popupWin.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>' +
                    '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />' +
                    '</head><body onload="window.print()"><div class="reward-body">' + printContents + '</div></html>');
                popupWin.onabort = function (event) {
                    popupWin.document.close();
                    popupWin.close();
                }
            } else {
                popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600');
                popupWin.document.open();
                popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</html>');
                popupWin.document.close();
            }
            popupWin.document.close();
            return true;
        };

        $scope.submitItems = function () {
            angular.forEach($scope.items.data, function (item) {
                if (item.quote_id == undefined) {
                    delete item.$$hashKey;
                    item.quote_id = $routeParams.quoteId;
                    itemService.createItem(item);
                }
            });
        };

        $scope.submitConditions = function () {
            angular.forEach($scope.conditions.data, function (condition) {
                if (condition.quote_id == undefined) {
                    delete condition.$$hashKey;
                    condition.quote_id = $routeParams.quoteId;
                    conditionService.createCondition(condition);
                }
            })
        };

        _fetchItems();
        _fetchConditions();
        _fetchQuote();
        _fetchClient();
        _fetchProject();


    }])
.directive('elastic', [
    '$timeout',
    function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, element) {
                $scope.initialHeight = $scope.initialHeight || element[0].style.height;
                var resize = function () {
                    element[0].style.height = $scope.initialHeight;
                    element[0].style.height = "" + (element[0].scrollHeight + 10) + "px";
                };
                element.on("input change", resize);
                $timeout(resize, 0);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use a filter.

Comment: lets us see your controller code. this logic should problably be done there.

Comment: I added it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-show` somthing like :

```
    <td class="item-row-quote">
<span ng-show = "item.unit  != null" class="quote-price-text" ng-model="row.dollarPerUnitText" id="dollarPerUnit">{{ '$/' + item.unit }}</span></td>
```

I hope that this is what you mean by `nothing` it is not clear.

Comment: Do you know why my question is not upvoted? @itsik I am trying to ask good questions on stackoverflow and people like you are giving good answers but I still get downvoted.

Comment: You added to match cods, be more specific, and make sure that first time reader will understand you completely.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one or two properties that may have null, then you can update them with empty strings in the controller.

```
DefaultController.$inject = ['$http'];

function DefaultController($http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.item;

    function getItem() {
        var config = {
            transformResponse: function(data, headers) {
                if (data) {
                    if (data.unit === null || data.unit === undefined) {
                        data.unit = '';
                    }
                }

                return data;
            }
        };

        $http.get('/api/items', config)
             .success(getItemCompleted);

        function getItemCompleted(data) {
            vm.item = data;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are having many properties that may be null and if you have control of the server side code, then see if you can handle there by returning empty arrays or empty list but not null if not then write a custom filter where you can loop through all the properties of an object and assign empty string to any property that is a falsy value

Comment: Thanks but I think for this application it is better to only use ng-show with a condition.

Comment: Do you know why my question is not upvoted?  I am trying to ask good questions on stackoverflow and people like you are giving good answers but I still get downvoted.